# Does applying a hotfix to master contradict the artifact promotion practice in artifactory?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, artifactory, gitops

I am part of a project where we are building an app and employing CI/CD to build test, deploy.
We create feature branches from develop, and then merge them into develop where the software is build and then subsequently is merged into staging and master when mature enough.

We are currently in a situation whereby in order to apply a hotfix to production, we need to build the master branch, but this contradicts my previous understanding that you should only build the develop branch and then promote the build to subsequent artifactory repositories.

I can't seem to find where I read it, but as I recall it was something to the effect of the above. Is what I read about artifactory incorrect, or is my git strategy flawed? Or are they incompatible?

Answer (score 0):

> This contradicts my previous understanding that you should only build the develop branch and then promote the build to subsequent artifactory repositories.

It does not contradict your understanding: the fact is, "[Best Practices for Structuring and Naming Artifactory Repositories](https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-structuring-naming-artifactory-repositories/)" simply does not mention the "patch" or "hotfix" scenario.

So in your case, you can have an hotfix branch from release, and promoting it back to production.
Looking at "[How Does Build Promotion work](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-does-build-promotion-work/)", that would mean a separate dedicated promotion workflow.